# If I have a list of character strings which are words separated by commas, how do I convert that into a DataFrame with word pairings and frequencies?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, nlp

Meta: Sorry about the badly phrased title, I'm really not sure how to describe what I'm asking in just one sentence.

I have a list of strings which looks like this:

```
'word1, word2, word3'
'word2, word3'
'word4, word3, word1'
'word2, word4'
```

From that array I want to generate a network graph, which requires my data to be structured as a Panda's DataFrame like this:

```
source, target, frequency
word1, word2, 1
word1, word3, 1
word2, word3, 2
word2, word4, 1
```

etc.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: The input is a list of strings, yes. And the output should be a Pd DF. I'll edit the question to make that more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate through the strings, split them on commas followed by a space, and use `IT.combinations` to form all pairs of words. A `collections.Counter` could be used to count the frequency of the pairs. And finally, the desired DataFrame could be built from the items in the `Counter`:

```
import collections
import itertools as IT
import pandas as pd

data = ['word1, word2, word3',
        'word2, word3',
        'word4, word3, word1',
        'word2, word4']

result = collections.Counter()
for item in data:
    for pair in IT.combinations(item.split(', '), 2):
        result[tuple(sorted(pair))] += 1

df = pd.DataFrame([pair+(freq,) for pair, freq in result.items()], columns=['source', 'target', 'freqency'])
print(df)
```

yields

```
  source target  freqency
0  word3  word4         1
1  word2  word4         1
2  word1  word3         2
3  word1  word2         1
4  word1  word4         1
5  word2  word3         2
```